# Conflicting feedback on my paraphrase: "on the grounds that X should be shared with Y" = "so that X [would/could] be shared with Y"

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, ambiguity

This is not a question about the meaning of "could" and "would". This is a question about which word fits the context.

I  got conflicting remarks on my paraphrase of a few sentences. I am not sure which is more valid.

Here is the original text (Note that the issue is about a bill that was introduced in 1971):

> Regionally extended benefits were introduced **on the grounds** that the additional costs related to the presence of structural unemployment in some regions **should be** shared with other regions and taken on by the government ...

This is my paraphrase (I used "could"):

> ... regionally extended benefits, which were introduced **so that** the additional costs of structural unemployment in some regions **could be** subsidized by government contributions and EI revenue from other regions.

#### Reader A's feedback (emphasis mine):

> I think it is a reasonable paraphrase. However, the wording of the original is rather **circumspect**. It expresses the reason for introducing the benefits **more as a hope or aspiration than as an expectation**, and it does not say what the actual effect was. Your use of "could" might be **too assertive**, and "**might**" might be better.

#### Reader B's feedback:

> Looked at another way, '**could**' could be seen as too **tentative**! 'Could' could imply that this was possible but might not happen (or that a choice was available). The original sentence tells us that the argument in favour of regionally extended benefits was that the additional cost in one region **should (for ethical or practical reasons, or both) be shared** with other regions and undertaken by the government'; regionally extended benefits were introduced for this reason; it is an **inevitable** assumption that the purpose of legislation based on a given argument is to **make compulsory** the action proposed by that argument . To reflect this,use "**would**":
>
> > ... which were introduced **so that** the additional costs of structural unemployment in some regions **would be** subsidized by government contributions and EI revenue from other regions.
>
> This is not a generalization about the possibility of replacing reason clauses with purpose clauses, and which verb (could,should,might etc.) is appropriate, which in other contexts may involve no ambiguity; but here the context does make a difference; **legislation may be permissive** ('You may do this') or **imperative** (You must do this'), and **the conventional use in purpose clauses of 'could' or 'might' can, as here, be ambiguous.**

I wholeheartedly agree with Reader B's feedback, except on the use of "would". It just doesn't sound right to me. So, I guess my question is, which makes more sense based on my context?

Comment: I think the use of "should" in the original is deontic. Your paraphrase's "could" sounds as if it means the legislation enables sharing. "Would" sounds as if the legislation tries to bring it about. Why are you paraphrasing the original? What is the purpose?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty It is for my paper. I can't quote the original because my sentence at the start has other information on the benefits (note the [...]). Are you able to write an answer for me? Would be super helpful ...

Comment: I'm not confident of understanding all the complexities of the question, so I'll let someone else answer it.

Comment: [not a legislation. Either a **piece of legislation**, a bill, etc. or just **legislation, no determiner.]

Comment: This is really about should and could (not would), the main difference in the original and yours is precisely that. The original does not posit a possibility. It straight out supports an ethical interpretation. I should go is not I could go.

Comment: @Lambie oh, thanks very much for the correction. And yes, that is what I am trying to avoid - any hint of possibility. This is looking difficult.

Comment: should here is a moral imperative. could is just a possibility. :)

Comment: @Lambie Got it. But do have any suggestions on how I can get rid of this problem?

Comment: introduced on the grounds  x **be shared** with y. on the grounds is pretty strong. I would leave it in. Since you will be using a footnote here, it's okay to be close to the original wording.

Comment: I don't think you understand the nature of quotations and paraphrasing. Not only can you quote an entire sentence inside quotation marks as part of your *own* sentence (you can start it off as you like and then change the capital letter in the source to a lowercase letter), but paraphrasing requires more changes than you've made. Essentially, all you're doing is modifying only a couple of words; that's not paraphrasing, it's actually quoting incorrectly. To paraphrase, you need to make more significant changes than just that. You need to essentially *summarize* in your own words.

Comment: But in order to really understand what you're after and why you think the original version doesn't work, you'd have to include the entire context, which means the part of your own sentence that you've left out.

Comment: @JasonBassford I actually do know what you are talking about regarding how we can quote entire sentences. But I don't want to quote it, mainly because I don't like the way the author phrased it. In particular, I don't like "related to the presence of", "shared", and "taken on by the government". And how else can I paraphrase that sentence? Much of those words need to be kept just like that. "regionally extended benefits", "structural unemployment", and "regions" are terms that cannot be changed because they are technical jargon. The rest are basic words (introduced, costs, etc) (cont.)

Comment: I tried *"which were introduced in order to subsidize the additional costs of structural unemployment in some regions by government contributions and by EI revenue from other regions"*. But look how far the object of "subsidize" is. It doesn't sound so good. I honestly don't understand how that is not a summary. I have changed the main style of the sentence.

Comment: So, ironically, in looking at the two versions, you're not changing parts of it enough—but you're also changing parts of it too much, because (at least not without further context) it's not saying the same thing at all. For instance, I don't see how *should be shared with other regions and taken on by the government* can be taken to mean *could be subsidized by government contributions and EI revenue from other regions.* Among other things, **should be** and **could be** don't mean the same thing at all. And it seems that **EI revenue** was added completely out of the blue.

Comment: Part of the problem is I don't fully understand the original in the first place without more context (it's not clearly written). However, my own rough pass at paraphrasing it would be something like this: *It was argued that the expense of introducing extended unemployment benefits in some regions should be partially paid for by other regions and managed by the government.* That completely restructures the sentence (paraphrasing) but, as far as I can tell, preserves the essential elements (so it's not misrepresenting anything).

Comment: @JasonBassford I changed those terms because the ones I used are the right terms. And those changes are fine because that is about the topic/issue and does not relate to English. Since I am working on this topic for a while now, I know that the right terminology is that "some regions subsidize other regions" and not something like "costs should be shared with other regions". Costs of benefits are not "shared", they are subsidized because, the regions that are subsidizing other regions now, have always been the doing so, they are net contributors. (cont.)

Comment: "Sharing" is the wrong word to describe someone who always just keeps on giving - that is subsidizing. Again, that has nothing to do with English. My problem was with the use of should/could. Your paraphrase does not mention that those extended benefits were actually introduced. You only mention it was argued. You have also omitted the required technical terms. I need to keep "regionally extended benefits" and "structural unemployment". The govt "contributed" to the program (not just managed it - and that is redundant since it is a federal program - by nature, it is managed by the govt.).

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback, but my problem was with the ambiguity with could/would. And I wanted to know which feedback made more sense *given* I stick with my version of the sentence style or construction.

Comment: Well, then you're saying the original author is wrong. But if that's the case, you shouldn't even be paraphrasing at all—you should just present your own ideas and forget about the other author altogether. Paraphrasing somebody else is **not** misrepresenting what they said—that's actually misrepresenting them. If they use the word *apple* and you use the word *orange*, but the specific fruit is essential to their meaning, then you're paraphrasing becomes a form of what's called reverse plagiarism: claiming that somebody said something (even if you're just paraphrasing), when they didn't.

Comment: And *argued* is a paraphrase of *should*. When you argue for something, you're saying that's how it should be.

Answer (score -1):

**"On the grounds that"** means *"because"*. It is used to show *reason*.

e.g.,  *"He objected to my proposal on the grounds that (= because) it would be too costly."*

It is meaningless if we use "so that" in this sentence :
*"He objected to my proposal so that it would be too costly."*

**"So that"** means *"in order that"*. It is used to show *"purpose"* :
*"He objected to my proposal so that a costly project could be rejected.*"

> Your paraphrase of the original sentence seems to me to be absolutely okay. It shows the purpose of the introduction of the regionally extended benefits and the purpose has become emphatic with the use of **"could"** in place of *"would"*.